# Optimization Problem for Exponential Polynomials

Tags: analysis, exponential-sum

**This question was [asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277864/an-optimization-problem-for-exponential-polynomials) on mathoverflow more than a year ago, with no answers**

Let $\omega$ be a primitive complex $n^{th}$ root of unity. I am interested in the following quantity
$$
\max_{f(n)\leq \ell \leq g(n)} \quad \min_{0<k\leq n-1} 
\left| 1+\omega^k+\omega^{2k}+\cdots+\omega^{(\ell-1)k}\right|^2,
$$
as $n$ goes to infinity. Note that the optimization simplifies to
$$
\max_{f(n)\leq \ell \leq g(n)} \quad \min_{0<k\leq n-1} 
\left| \frac{\sin (\pi \ell k/n)}{\sin (\pi k/n)}\right|^2,
$$
and for concreteness case I don't mind taking $f(n)=\log^2 n, g(n)=\sqrt{n}-$not the iterated log but square of log.

I know the minimum will in general can be very small (at least for arbitrary sums of roots of unity as in [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277864/an-optimization-problem-for-exponential-polynomials) by Terry Tao) but what if we are free to look at multiple lengths for the sum, and take consecutive powers, things must improve, but how much?

**Edit:**
The related problem
$$
\min_{0<k\leq n-1}\quad \max_{f(n)\leq \ell \leq g(n)} 
\left| \frac{\sin (\pi \ell k/n)}{\sin (\pi k/n)}\right|^2,
$$
which may be easier is also of interest.

One can take $n$ prime, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If $\omega$ is an $n^{th}$-root of unity, then so is $\omega^m$ for any integer $m$. So your minimum is just over all the $n^{th}$ roots of unity $\omega$ other than $1$. That is $$\min_{\underset {\omega \ne 1}{\omega^n = 1}}\left|1 + \dots +\omega^{\ell - 1}\right|^2$$

But the expression being minimized can be expressed as $$\left|\frac{\omega^{\ell} - 1}{\omega -1}\right|^2$$

This is minimized by sending the top to $0$ and maximized by sending the bottom to $0$. If $\omega = e^{i2k\pi/n}$, then the expression is minimized over $k$ by choosing $k$ as close to $\frac n\ell$ as possible. The result minimum is maximized over $\ell$ by choosing $\ell$ so that $\frac n\ell$ is as far from integer as possible.

And finally, we look at what happens as $n \to \infty$. As $n$ gets larger, $\omega$ divides the circle up into smaller and smaller parts, which means that we can find values for $\omega^\ell$ closer and closer to $1$, thus making the minimum ratio $k$ smaller, regardless of which $\ell$ we pick.

I.e., the limit you seek is $0$.